Upgrading WiX project to v4 fails
I'm experiencing problems attempting to upgrade my WiX project to v4:
[06/25/2024 16:58:06.115]: Converting project file Setup.wixproj...
[06/25/2024 16:58:06.129]: *** ERROR ***: Import failed with an exception.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\source\repos\Internal - CRM 2011\Product Importer\Code\Setup\$(SolutionDir)Setup\Filter.xslt'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at FireGiant.HeatWave.ProjectConversion.VotiveProjectConverter.ProcessHeatTransforms(XDocument doc, String projectFolder)
   at FireGiant.HeatWave.ProjectConversion.VotiveProjectConverter.<ConvertAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at FireGiant.HeatWave.ProjectConversion.VotiveProjectConverter.<TryConvertAsync>d__9.MoveNext().
[06/25/2024 16:58:06.129]: ---- Project Setup: Converted 7 files.
[06/25/2024 16:58:06.129]: ---- Total time: 00.022
[06/25/2024 16:58:06.129]: ========== Import complete:  1 errors, 0 warnings

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise Edition (Version 17.10.3), with the 'HeatWave for VS2022' (v1.0.4) extension installed.
Trying to build the solution with the current WiX project crashes VS, so I've read that the recommendation is to update the project. On the WiX site, they recommend using the HeatWave VS extension to manage the project update.
I've tried implementing the solution mentioned by @woozer, but this didn't appear to have any affect.
Background
I've inherited a .NET Framework windows forms app that needed some work and had to be updated to .NET Framework v4.8 before I would begin. The solution already contained the WiX project and, according the project file, the current version is v3.8
<ProductVersion>3.8</ProductVersion>

I'm not sure why, when the WiX project is included in the solution, it crashes VS when built, perhaps it's because of the older version. Anyway, my goal is to try to upgrade to the latest WiX version in the hopes that it clears the issue.
I'd be grateful for any advice and guidance.
Kaine
